# Problem with generate pdf and display images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a problem with displaying the images in pdf. 5 out of 100 attempts work. After saving all data to database, there is opened a new site with pdf generated by gem *wkhtmltopdf*. During getting the image from path /rails/active_storage/blobs/... service is stopped and report isn't generated. There are no errors on consoles .Only solution is stopped the server ( ctrl+c ) and start again the server.

The server is stopped on request :
***Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/...***

I display image by line : 
***<%= image_tag(@object.image, class: '') if @object.image.attached?  %>***

There is a method for generate report (above this code there are the varialbes to display in report )

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    redirect_to index
  end
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "Raport",
           template: "myFolder/report.html.erb",
           :footer => {
               :font_size => '8'
           }
  end
end
```

I'm using rails 5.2.3, ruby 2.5.3

I'm expect to generate the pdf with images.

Comment: which gem you used for generating pdf?

Comment: I use   gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 1.1'

Comment: use this code for displayin image on pdf `wicked_pdf_image_tag(@object.image, class: '') if @object.image.attached?`

Comment: I've tried but i got  error **no implicit conversion of ActiveStorage::Attached::One into String**

Comment: add this method to app controller `def wicked_blob_path(file)
  ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, file.blob.key)
end`  use this code in your pdf file `= image_tag(wicked_blob_path(@object.image), alt: '_') if @object.image.attached?`